# rails update multiple records in single model and single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

iam new to rails, i have model(welcome) and i want to update the model with single form where the form has duplicate fields . 
only second field updates the model ..

> Update multiple records in single model with  single form_submit

routes

```js
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/new'
  post 'welcome/create'
  root 'welcome#index'
```

welcomecontroller

```js
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def new
    @article = Welcome.new
  end
  def create
    @article = Welcome.new(user_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to welcome_new_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  private
  
  def user_params
    params.require(:welcome).permit(:name , :descrip  )
  end
end
```

welcomeindex view

```js
<%= form_for@ article, url: welcome_create_path do |f | %>
  <%= f.text_field: name %>
  <%= f.text_field: descrip %>
  <%= f.text_field: name %>
  <%= f.text_field: descrip %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only the second set of fields are being updated because you have duplicate names for the fields. Give each field a unique name and it should work.

```
<%= form_for@ article, url: welcome_create_path do |f | %>
  <%= f.text_field: name1 %>
  <%= f.text_field: descrip1 %>
  <%= f.text_field: name2 %>
  <%= f.text_field: descrip2 %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

You will need to update the controller method user_params accordingly

```
def user_params
  params.require(:welcome).permit(:name1 , :descrip1, :name2 , :descrip2 )
end
```

Comment: thanks :).  Actually i want to update multiple records in single model with with single for submit ..

Comment: I answered the question as posed. This is a different question which you should start as a new thread. You should accept my answer as it answers your question and provides a workable solution.